# Redux not updating store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning redux and I have an issue with react updating the data from the store.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import App from "./App";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: counter
});
function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return state + 1;
    case "DECREMENT":
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
  console.log(store.getState());
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{store.getState()}</p>
      <button onClick={() => store.dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT" })}>
        Increment
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

For some reason the `store.getState()` stays the the same despite a visible update in the redux dev tools

[Redux dev tools view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDeLQ.png)

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-p8vm7h?file=src/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another option, I would suggest you to go and check the basic tutorial of `Redux` in their website, You do need to make `React` know your state.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider, connect } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import store from "./App.js";
import App from "./App";

const store = createStore(counter);

function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return state + 1;
    case "DECREMENT":
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    count: state
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onIncrementClick: () => {
      dispatch({type: "INCREMENT" })
    }
  }
}

const App = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
  function AppComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.count}</p>
      <button onClick={props.onIncrementClick}>
        Increment
      </button>
    </div>
  );
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Note that it's better to access dispatch via `props`, i.e. `props.dispatch(...)`. The component might not have direct access to the store like this example.

Comment: @AtanasB Note that in the documentation there is a more organized way of defining the actions and reducers, when you use multiple actions, reducers and components :)

Answer (score 0):

Because `react` has no idea that the store is changing.
You need to use hooks provided by `react-redux` which binds your component to `redux` state so that you could listen to changes in your redux state.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider, useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import store from "./App.js";
import App from "./App";


function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return state + 1;
    case "DECREMENT":
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const store = createStore(counter);

function App() {
  const counter = useSelector(state => state);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{counter}</p>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT" })}>
        Increment
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```